# What is the difference between setting the priority for the main thread or not?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have this Question :

Create and run a thread that writes "Hello friends" on screen. The main Thread waits for it only 500 milliseconds. Then run the program again after you give the created Thread lower priority than the main Thread. This time, the main Thread should wait for it 10 milliseconds. Do you notice anything? Why?

I want to know the difference that made by `Thread.setPriority(n)`
first code and second get the same output

first code

```
public class Q2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread2 myThread = new Thread2();
        myThread.start();
        System.out.println("main thread");
    }
}
class Thread2 extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            join(500);
            System.out.println("Hello Friends from thread2");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

seconde code

```
public class Q2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread2 myThread = new Thread2();
        myThread.start();
        System.out.println("main thread");
    }
}
class Thread2 extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            setPriority(MIN_PRIORITY);
            join(500);
            System.out.println("Hello Friends from thread2");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `main` thread **never** waits for anything, it kicks of `myThread`, prints and exits immediately. I'm not sure why you are calling `Thread.join` on itself. This is not how `join` is intended to work, and is really rather odd...

Comment: @BoristheSpider does that mean the method setPriority won't make a different ? ,, how can I use join method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the main Thread should wait for it 10 milliseconds

That's not what your code does. The `join` should be in the main thread, not in the newly created thread:

```
Thread2 myThread = new Thread2();
myThread.start();
myThread.join(10);
```

I assume the whole idea of this exercise is to see the difference between two threads with different priorities. Giving a thread a lower priority may delay its scheduled execution. When the main thread waits for a smaller duration for the new thread to finish, the outputs of the two threads may interleave since the main thread may continue to reach the `System.out` before the second thread does.

The documentation of the [`Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) class explains what a thread priority is:

> Every thread has a priority. Threads with higher priority are executed in preference to threads with lower priority.

Answer (score 1):

In general, don't extend `Thread`, you should wrap a `Runnable` instead.

The Thread priority is

- just a hint, the OS can and does ignore it if you don't have the right permissions.
- It will only matter if you don't have free CPU.  If you have free CPU every thread which wants to run can run.
- it really won't matter if you are putting your thread to sleep. e.g. a join.

The only difference it could make is when your machine is very busy, it would take a little longer to wake up from the sleep. e.g. instead of taking say 500 to 501 ms to do the `join`, it might take 510 ms sometimes.

> how can I use join method ?

The purpose of `join` is to wait for *another* thread to finish up to some time limit.  If you join on yourself, this is effectively the same as `Thread.sleep`  I suggest using `Thread.sleep` instead as this is less confusing.

Comment: thanks , got it . so the priority method won't matter because the main method always have the max priority ?

Comment: @Independent The main thread always has the "normal" priority, which is the priority it starts with.  You can increase this.  The priority really doesn't matter if you are asleep.

Answer (score 1):

First, from the documentation for [`Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html):

> Waits at most millis milliseconds for this thread to die. A timeout of 0 means to wait forever.

So when you have two `Thread` instances, lets say the current one and a new one, you can cause the current thread to wait for the new one to die:

```
final Thread t = new Thread(() -> System.out.println("Test"));
t.start();
t.join();
```

So now our current thread (the one creating `t`) will wait for `t` to die, then continue. This method makes an **asynchronous** task **synchronous**.

Now, what does calling `join` *in a `Thread`* do? Well, it means that the thread will wait for **itself** to die. This is the same as `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep()`.

So what does your code *actually do*?

Well, `main` calls the following code:

```
Thread2 myThread = new Thread2();
myThread.start();
System.out.println("main thread");
```

There is nothing here that makes `main` wait for anything, `main` dies.

Now your `Thread2` (**terrible** name for a `class`) does the following:

```
setPriority(MIN_PRIORITY);
join(500);
System.out.println("Hello Friends from thread2");
```

So it sets its own priority, it then waits for `500` milliseconds for itself to die. Obviously it doesn't die in that time. It then prints.

### TL;DR: `setPriority` does next to nothing in this code

---

One further note, do not `extends Thread`, use a `Runnable`.

Comment: `setPriority` usually does next to nothing, but it does even less if you are blocking. ;)

Comment: thanks a lot , I used extends because it is an exercise an , in a real program I use a runnable

Comment: @Independent sorry, but when it's "_an exercise_" it's **more important** do things correctly.